# Difference between OpenMP threadprivate and private

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, private

I am trying to parallelize a C program using OpenMP.

I would like to know more about:

1. The differences between the **threadprivate** directive and the **private** clause and
2. In which cases we must use any of them.

As far as I know, the difference is the global scope with **threadprivate** and the preserved value across parallel regions. I found in several examples that when a piece of code contains some global/static variables that must be privatized, these variables are included in a **threadprivate** list and their initial values are copied into the private copies using **copyin**.

However, is there any rule that prevents us to use the **private** clause to deal with global/static variables? perhaps any implementation detail?

I couldn't find any explanation in the OpenMP3.0 specification.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The most important differences you have to memorize:

- A `private` variable is local to a region and will most of the time be placed on the **stack**. The lifetime of the variable's privacy is the duration defined of the data scoping clause. Every thread (including the master thread) makes a private copy of the original variable (the new variable is no longer storage-associated with the original variable).
- A `threadprivate` variable on the other hand will be most likely placed in the **heap** or in the **[thread local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage)** (that can be seen as a global memory local to a thread). A `threadprivate` variable persist across regions (depending on some restrictions). The master thread uses the original variable, all other threads make a private copy of the original variable (the master variable is still storage-associated with the original variable).

---

- There are also more tricky differences:

  - Variables defined as `private` are undefined for each thread upon entering the construct and the corresponding shared variable is undefined when the parallel construct is exited; the initial status of a `private` pointer is undefine.
  - But data in the `threadprivate` common blocks should be assumed to be undefined on entry to the first parallel region unless a `copyin` clause is specified. When a common block appears in a `threadprivate` directive, each thread copy is initialized once prior to its first use.
- The [OpenMP Specifications](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) (section 2.14.2) actually give a very good description (and also more detailled) of the `threadprivate` directive:

  > Each copy of a `threadprivate` variable is initialized once, in the manner specified by the program, but at an unspecified point in the program prior to the first reference to that copy. The storage of all copies of a `threadprivate` variable is freed according to how static variables are handled in the base language, but at an unspecified point in the program.
  >
  > A program in which a thread references another thread’s copy of a `threadprivate` variable is non-conforming.
  >
  > The content of a `threadprivate` variable can change across a task scheduling point if the executing thread switches to another task that modifies the variable. For more details on task scheduling, see Section 1.3 on page 14 and Section 2.11 on page 113.
  >
  > In `parallel` regions, references by the master thread will be to the copy of the variable in the thread that encountered the `parallel` region.
  >
  > During a sequential part references will be to the initial thread’s copy of the variable. The values of data in the initial thread’s copy of a `threadprivate` variable are guaranteed to persist between any two consecutive references to the variable in the program.
  >
  > The values of data in the `threadprivate` variables of non-initial threads are guaranteed to persist between two consecutive active `parallel` regions only if all the following conditions hold:
  >
  > - Neither `parallel` region is nested inside another explicit `parallel` region.
  > - The number of threads used to execute both `parallel` regions is the same.
  > - The thread affinity policies used to execute both `parallel` regions are the same.
  > - The value of the *dyn-var* internal control variable in the enclosing task region is *false* at entry to both `parallel` regions.
  >
  > If these conditions all hold, and if a `threadprivate` variable is referenced in both regions, then threads with the same thread number in their respective regions will reference the same copy of that variable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the links! So, may I conclude the following?:

1) In case I need to privatize automatic data, I should use the **private** clause, and
2) In case I need to privatize file-scope, global-scope data; I should use the **threadprivate** directive.

Comment: @L30nardoSV: What do you mean with "automatic data"?

Comment: I mean local variables.

Comment: @L30nardoSV: if you mean local variables, which you don't need after the parallel region anymore or which you will redefine after the parallel region... then **yes**! You don't **need** to (thread)privatize **all** your variables (you can let them shared), you only have to (thread)privatize them if you want to **modify** them. (I would also recommend you, if you don't already know to learn the differences between heap and stack.)

Comment: When would threadprivate ever be on the heap? As far as I understand it should be implemented with TLS.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker, okay I read through it again and then again and I still don't see where threadprivate would be implemented in the heap. Threadprivate acts on static variables and static variables use static memory allocation which has nothing to do with the heap.