# common block in openmp Fortran

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, fortran77

My code is following:

```
 program
 ...
 ! Loop which I want to parallelize
 !$OMP parallel DO
 I = 1, N
 ...
 call FORD(i,j)
  ...
 !$OMP END parallel DO
 end program

  subroutine FORD(i,j)
  logical servo,genflg,lapflg
  dimension c(nvarc)
  dimension zl(3),zg(3),v1(3,3),v2(3,3),rn(3),
 .          rcg1(3),rcg2(3),ru1(3),ru2(3),
 .          rott1(3),rott2(3),velr(3),dt(3),
 .          dfs(3),ftu(3),fnr(3),amomet(3
  common /contact/ iab11,iab22,xx2,yy2,zz2,
 .                 ra1,rb1,rc1,ra2,rb2,rc2,
 .                 v1,v2,
 .                 xg1,yg1,zg1,xg2,yg2,zg2
  common /ellip/ b1,c1,f1,g1,h1,d1,
 .               b2,c2,f2,g2,h2,p2,q2,r2,d2
  common /root/ root1,root2
  common /tab1/
 .       itype(ndim1),nconti(5),nvarc,
 .       nconta,nconta1
  common /bal1/
 .       ra(5),rb(5),rc(5),
 .       amomen(ndim),fwall(6),press(3),wmomet(6,2),
 .       rot(ndim),ttheta(ndim*3),rstp(ndim*3),forces(ndim),
 .       ssampl(3,3),edserv(3,3),tdisp(ndim),adisp(ndim),vel(ndim),
 .       del(3),xmax(3)

CALL CONDACT(genflg,lapflg)
return
end subroutine

SUBROUTINE CONDACT(genflg,lapflg)
implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
logical rflag,dflag,error,gmvflg,grvflg,ctrlflg,depflg
  parameter (ndim1 = 20002)
  parameter (ndim = 3*ndim1)
  parameter (nkmm = 9000000)
  parameter (nkwall = 50000)
  character*4 hed
  logical genflg,lapflg,fast
  dimension v1(3,3),v2(3,3)
  common /contact/ iab11,iab22,xx2,yy2,zz2,
 .                 ra1,rb1,rc1,ra2,rb2,rc2,
 .                 v1,v2,
 .                 xg1,yg1,zg1,xg2,yg2,zg2
  common /ellip/ b1,c1,f1,g1,h1,d1,b2,c2,f2,g2,h2,p2,q2,r2,d2
  common /switch/ nk
  common /root/ root1,root2
  common /nroot/ rt(5),nrt
  common /bal2/xmax(3)

 call function f(x)
 C
 C...... 
 C

 RETURN
 END

  function f(x)
  implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
  common /contact/ iab11,iab22,xx2,yy2,zz2,
 .                 ra1,rb1,rc1,ra2,rb2,rc2,
 .                 v1,v2,
 .                 xg1,yg1,zg1,xg2,yg2,zg2
  common /ellip/ b1,c1,f1,g1,h1,d1,
 .               b2,c2,f2,g2,h2,p2,q2,r2,d2
  common /switch/ nk
  common /nroot/ rt(5),nrt
  dimension a(3,3),b(3),v1(3,3),v2(3,3)
  ..
  ..
  ..
  ..
  end
```

my question is inside the parallel loop, does all variable (within common block or outside of common block) in each subroutine are private? 
1. If not, should I use threadprivate for the common blocks and private the variables in each subroutine after declaration?
2. Each thread passes through 2 subroutine and one function. Subroutines has some same common block and variables. if I use threadprivate common blocks for each subroutine, how do the variable values pass through the entire program for a single thread.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Eliminate common blocks.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. So, Will I just declare the variable? That will make them private for each thread?

Comment: Remove common blocks means all local variables as arguments, among other things.

Comment: Or make the common blocks `threadprivate` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209196/fortran-77-common-blocks-in-multithreading-c-application/32213488#32213488

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! But I have tried with threadprivate but got segmentation failure. (I read somewhere that threadprivate common block takes huge memory space/stack.)

Comment: Just to reiterate what Jeff was saying, you should spend some effort in making the serial version of your code work without common blocks. There are a lot of reasons why, but [here's](http://iprc.soest.hawaii.edu/users/furue/improve-fortran.html) a quick overview on the how. Once you have succeeded in doing this, then you can re-tackle the problem of serializing this program with OpenMP.

Comment: @VladimirF, can I rewrite the common block variable inside the subroutine or function, once I declared the common block in the main thread? or it will just pass the variable value of main thread?

Comment: Ask a new question and show the code.

Comment: @VladimirF, here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446564/issue-with-common-blockfortran-in-open-mp-parallel-programming