# Issue with common block in OpenMP parallel programming

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, fortran-common-block

I have a few questions about using common blocks in parallel programming in Fortran.

1. My subroutines have common blocks. Do I have to declare all the common blocks and threadprivate in the parallel do region?
2. How do they pass information? I want seperate common clock for each thread and want them to pass information through the end of parallel region. Does it happen here?
3. My `Ford` subroutine changes some variables in common blocks and `Condact` subroutine overwrites over them again but the function uses the values from `Condact` subroutine. Do the second subroutine and function copy the variables from the previous subroutine for each thread?

   ```
   program
   ...
   ! Loop which I want to parallelize
   !$OMP parallel DO
   !do I need to declear all common block and threadprivate them here?
   I = 1, N
   ...
   call FORD(i,j)
   ...
   !$OMP END parallel DO
   end program

   subroutine FORD(i,j)
   dimension zl(3),zg(3)
   common /ellip/ b1,c1,f1,g1,h1,d1,
   .               b2,c2,f2,g2,h2,p2,q2,r2,d2
   common /root/ root1,root2
   !$OMP threadprivate (/ellip/,/root/)
   !this subroutine rewrite values of b1, c1 and f1 variable.
   CALL CONDACT(genflg,lapflg)
   return
   end subroutine

   SUBROUTINE CONDACT(genflg,lapflg)
   common /ellip/ b1,c1,f1,g1,h1,d1,b2,c2,f2,g2,h2,p2,q2,r2,d2
   !$OMP threadprivate (/ellip/)
   ! this subroutine rewrite b1, c1 and f1 again
   call function f(x)
   RETURN
   END

   function f(x)
   common /ellip/ b1,c1,f1,g1,h1,d1,
   .               b2,c2,f2,g2,h2,p2,q2,r2,d2
   !$OMP threadprivate (/ellip/)
   ! here the function uses the value of b1, c1, f1 from CONDAT subroutine.
   end
   ```

Comment: Global data and parallelization is generally a bad idea. Using common blocks is a worse idea. Is this an old code, or do you write something new?  You definitely should first try to get rid of common blocks in your code.

Comment: The other question is, what kind of data it is you have in the common block. Is something which is just defined for each (i,j) and reused upon each call? Or is it something to contain the result for all (i,j)?

Comment: @haraldkl, I am trying to parallelize using open mp a very old code full of common blocks! (I know I can use module but I want to try with common block and threadprivate 1st)

Comment: @haraldkl, the common block variables overwritten each time upon each call. They just hold some data during the calculation process inside the subroutine. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: I am really sorry for you, but in your other question you asked how to get rid of those common blocks, and this really is the way to go. Believe it or not, spending the effort to get rid of them, will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: Yes, in that case it is perfectly suitable to declare them as variables inside the called routine, as your OpenMP loop is outside that they would automatically be private, which is great.

Comment: @haraldkl, Thanks for your quick reply. The problem is function f(x) does not overwrite any variable. It uses the variable overwritten from CONDAT subroutine. What to do for this part?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure I understand your question here. As pointed out in your other question, you would need to change the interface of F and Condact, to get these variables b1, c1, f1... passed as arguments.

Comment: @haraldkl, Ford subroutine overwrite the variables-> I can easily declare them as variable inside the subroutine.  Condact subroutine overwrites the variable again but I need to pass them to the function. For this part I need to change the interface. Thank you very much. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly as the comment above says I would strongly advise against the use of `common` especially in modern code, and mixing global data and parallelism is just asking for a world of pain - in fact global data is just a bad idea full stop.

OK, your questions:

> 1. My subroutines has common blocks. Do I have to declare all the
>      common block and threadprivate in the parallel do region?

No,`threadprivate` is a declarative directive, and should be used only in the declarative part of the code, and it must appear after every declaration.

> 2. How do they pass information? I want seperate common clock for each
>      thread and want them to pass information through the end of parallel
>      region. Does it happen here?

As you suspect each thread will gets its own version of the `common` block. When you enter the first parallel region the values in the block will be undefined, unless you use `copyin` to broadcast the values from the master thread. For subsequent parallel regions the values will be retained as long as the number of threads used in each region is the same. Between regions the values in the common block will be those of the master thread.

> 3. Are those common block accessible through the subroutine? My Ford subroutine rewrite some variables in common block and Condat
>      subroutine rewrite over them again but the function uses the values
>      from Condat subroutine. Is that possible rewrite and pass the common
>      block variable using threadprivate here?

I have to admit I am unsure what you are asking here. But if you are asking whether common can be used to communicate variables between different sub-programs in OpenMP code, the answer is yes, just as in serial Fortran (note capitalisation)

Comment: @lanBush thanks for you answar. The 3rd question: b1=2 in the main program, In Ford subroutine, it overwrites b1=4, so Condact subroutine and function f(x) will see b1=4. Right?

Answer (score 0):

How about converting the common blocks into modules?

Change `common /root/ root1, root2` to `use gammax`, then make a new file `root.f` that contains:

```
module root
implicit none
save
real :: root1, root2
!$omp threadprivate( root1, root2 )
end module root
```

Comment: Yes, that is an alternative to common blocks. But similar questuons are still there.