# Private and public variables inside a module and a a subroutine in OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, fortran90

I am trying to parallelize a fairly complicated simulation code used for oil field calculations.

My question is, if I can declare a variable or some allocatable arrays and a few subroutines in a module, then use this module in another module/subroutine which contains the parallel region, will those variables and arrays be considered private to each thread (i.e. they will have separate copies of those variables and changes made to a variables in a thread won't be seen by other threads) or they'll be shared?

Like this:

```
module m2
implicit none
integer :: global
contains

    subroutine s2()
        implicit none
        integer :: tid
        tid = ! Some calculation
    end subroutine s2
end module m2

module m1
    use m2
    implicit none
contains
    subroutine s1
        !$omp parallel do
            do i=1, 9
                call s2()
            end do
        !$omp end parallel do
    end subroutine s1
end module m1
```

Will `tid` and `global` be private or shared?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module variables are always **`shared`** in OpenMP unless you use the `threadprivate` directive. See [Difference between OpenMP threadprivate and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022133/difference-between-openmp-threadprivate-and-private) for detailed description of `threadprivate`. So `global` will be shared.

The local variable `tid` is declared in the subroutine and called from the parallel region. Therefore it will be **`private`** unless it has the `save` attribute.

(Note that initialization like `integer :: tid = 0` also adds the `save` implicitly, so be careful.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it clears things up. But will this apply to variables defined inside nested subroutines? Like defining another subroutine inside `s2` and having variables in it, they'll be private too?

Comment: Yes, they will be private too.